# Query Builder API Intiation

Tags: aem, query-builder

I am implementing a Java module to fetch the pages which has a particular component.Here i have  initiated Query builder . But the query builder object is returning null. How should i initiate this queryBuilder. Bellow is the code snippet

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = slingScriptHelper
                .getService(QueryBuilder.class);
com.day.cq.search.Query queryObj = queryBuilder.createQuery(
                PredicateGroup.create(predicateMap), session);
```

Comment: I assume you're calling this from another service? at which point are you running this code? maybe it's to early and the QueryBuilderImpl component isn't ready yet. version of AEM ?

Comment: Hi ,Am using AEM 5.6.1 The services are available in service module.

Comment: as above again: Are you calling this from a @service? how do you obtain the SlingScriptHelper? I guess it would be benefitial if you just pasted the whole class ;)

Comment: Hi I am Using this code,@Reference
 public QueryBuilder queryBuilder;

Comment: i'm asking for the third time already mate: are you doing it FROM a service? cause you can only @Reference a component from within an osgi service

Comment: Yeah consuming Querybuilder with in another service. It worked  now. earlier bundle had some issues . Cleared the class files and updated the bundle it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to bundle issue. Restarted the CQ5 worked.